# Page Size is not being selected in ng grid on first page load

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Issue with page size with ng grid

Current Code of page size

```
$scope.pagingOptions = {
            pageSizes: [2,15, 25, 50],
            pageSize: 2,
            currentPage: 1
        };
```

on first time page load my page size drop down showing one space,2 should be selected in page size dropdown

[image: page size dropdown]

[image: space is showing]

Html Code

```
<select ng-model="pagingOptions.pageSize" style="float: left; height: 27px; width: 100px;" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
          <option value="? number:2 ?"></option>
          <option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="2">2</option>
          <option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="15">15</option>
          <option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="25">25</option>
          <option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

So how to make dropdown selected with 2

**Updated**

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y8ssuV9yRqgkbWKXhLpC?p=preview)

**Updated**

During creating plunker i have found that issue is related to angular js version

issue with

> AngularJS v1.4.1

working fine with

> AngularJS v1.0.2

But i want to fix this with

> AngularJS v1.4.1

due to my project faced other issue if i change angular js version

Comment: Please provide a working plunker example.

Comment: @Michael i have added plunker

Comment: As it stands it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that `pageSize` must be defined as a string instead of a number. Seems like there was a change in the angular `select` directive...

```
  pageSize: '5',
```